Aligning Nodes in HBox to Left and Right
I want the "Shuffle" button to align on the right (over the Ace of Hearts on the right), and the "answer" Text to align on the left.  However, they're only aligning in the center (as pictured).

Here's what I've written to accomplish that:
    topNodes.getChildren().add(answer);
    topNodes.getChildren().add(btShuffle);
    topNodes.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    answer.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT);
    btShuffle.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_RIGHT);

I then added:

topNodes to a VBox
the VBox to a StackPane
the StackPane to the scene

I'm struggling to figure out where the problem lies and what I should do differently.

Maybe an AnchorPane is more appropriate - rather than a HBox?

You don’t have to use HBox and VBox for everything.  Try BorderPane topNodes = new BorderPane(null, null, btShuffle, null, answer); instead.

When it comes to layout, there cannot be one fixed solution. You need to figure out which layout best suites to your purpose (considering other factors).
Below is a quick demonstration, to let you know that you can get the desired behavior using five different layouts..(it can be more as well)

Using HBox: Add a spacer in between, with hgrow to stretch the space, pushing adjacent nodes to the far ends.
Using StackPane: Set individual alignments to the nodes, so that StackPane will take care of layouting them.
Using GridPane: Add column constraints with each column have the separate alignment set.
Using BorderPane: Add nodes to left and right for the layout to take care of it.
Using AnchorPane: Add offset to the nodes towards left and right.
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AlignLeftRightDemo extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.setSpacing(20);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 450);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Align left and right");
        primaryStage.show();
        root.getChildren().addAll(buildBox("HBox", buildHBox()),
                buildBox("StackPane", buildStackPane()),
                buildBox("BorderPane", buildBorderPane()),
                buildBox("GridPane", buildGridPane()),
                buildBox("AnchorPane", buildAnchorPane()));
    }

    private AnchorPane buildAnchorPane() {
        AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
        Label lbl = getLabel();
        Button btn = getButton();
        anchorPane.getChildren().addAll(lbl,btn);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(lbl, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(lbl, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(lbl, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(btn, 0.0);
        return anchorPane;
    }

    private Node buildGridPane() {
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        ColumnConstraints col1 = new ColumnConstraints();
        col1.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
        col1.setHalignment(HPos.LEFT);
        ColumnConstraints col2 = new ColumnConstraints();
        col2.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
        col2.setHalignment(HPos.RIGHT);
        gridPane.getColumnConstraints().addAll(col1,col2);
        gridPane.addRow(0, getLabel(), getButton());
        return gridPane;
    }

    private BorderPane buildBorderPane() {
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        Label lbl = getLabel();
        BorderPane.setAlignment(lbl, Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        Button btn = getButton();
        BorderPane.setAlignment(btn, Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
        borderPane.setLeft(lbl);
        borderPane.setRight(btn);
        return borderPane;
    }

    private StackPane buildStackPane() {
        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
        Label lbl = getLabel();
        StackPane.setAlignment(lbl, Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        Button btn = getButton();
        StackPane.setAlignment(btn, Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
        stackPane.getChildren().addAll(lbl, btn);
        return stackPane;
    }

    private HBox buildHBox() {
        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Pane spacer = new Pane();
        HBox.setHgrow(spacer, Priority.ALWAYS);
        hBox.getChildren().addAll(getLabel(), spacer, getButton());
        return hBox;
    }

    // Below are just for demonstration purpose,. ignore them
    private Node buildBox(String title, Node node) {
        Label titleLbl = new Label(title);
        titleLbl.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 14px;-fx-font-weight:bold;");
        return new VBox(8, titleLbl, node);
    }

    private Label getLabel() {
        Label lbl = new Label("Invalid expression!");
        lbl.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 14px;");
        return lbl;
    }

    private Button getButton() {
        Button btn = new Button("Shuffle");
        btn.setStyle("-fx-font-size:18px;");
        return btn;
    }
}

UPDATE: Below is the screenshot of what @James_D is mentioning in the comment.


The most obvious layout class for this, to me at least, would be AnchorPane.  Anchor one to the left and one to the right.  This is pretty much what AnchorPane was created for.

To an extent I agree with that. But mostly I never use AnchorPane based on the fact that I need to provide the offset values. It will be very hard to work with AnchorPane for aligning the nodes. For example, in the above case, we need to provide the exact pixel value for the label to align with button(vertically center). I would prefer for the layout to take care of that stuff.

Updated the example to include AnchorPane and its drawback.

Attach the label to the top and bottom as well.

Nice demo. I agree that this is a good use case for AnchorPane. The real choice to make between these layouts is how you want it to behave if there is not enough space. With AnchorPane and StackPane the components will overlap (the button will appear on top as it is added last). With HBox and GridPane both components will be smaller than their preferred size (and the text will be truncated). With BorderPane the button (and eventually the label) is clipped.

@DaveB Thanks for mentioning that. I am not aware, that setting top & bottom to 0 will align the node to center. Corrected the desc in example.

Using JavaFX 17, you can try this code to have your button positioned to the right side of the window (with a label to the left side) within a HBox:
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        Label lbl = new Label("Some message here!");
        Button btn = new Button("Click me");
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        HBox.setHgrow(pane, Priority.ALWAYS);
        HBox hb = new HBox();
        hb.getChildren().addAll(lbl, pane, btn);
        Scene scene = new Scene(hb, 400, 200);
        stage.setTitle("My Application");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}

